# Show $\left\{(-1)^{n}+1 / n: n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}\right\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ has no interior points.

Tags: real-analysis

Show $S:= \left\{(-1)^{n}+1 / n: n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}\right\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ has no interior points.

The original question is $S$ as subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is easy because of density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  But I think the above should be true as well, but not sure how to prove.

Answer (score 0):

The density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ is not needed for, and as far as I can tell does not contribute to, the conclusion that $S\subseteq\mathbb R.$ To say that $S\subseteq\mathbb R$ only means that every member of $S$ is a member of $\mathbb R.$

If you mean interior points as a subset of $\mathbb R$ (as opposed to interior points as a subset of $\mathbb Q$) then consider what an interior point is: A point $x$ is an interior point of a set $T\subseteq\mathbb R$ if and only if some open interval in $\mathbb R$ contains $x$ as a member and is a subset of $T.$ But every nonempty open interval is uncountably infinite, whereas your set $S$ is countably infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ has no isolated points, for a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ to have nonempty interior, the set $S$ must contain one of its limit points.  But the limit points of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ are $\pm 1$, neither of which lies in $S$.  So $S$ has empty interior.